# Not able to transfer information between rootVC and modally presented otherVC?

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to use information from one rootVC in a modally presented otherVC. Here is the setup for it:

```
protocol OtherVCDelegate {
    func didHitOK()
    func didHitCancel()
}


class ViewController: UIViewController, OtherVCDelegate {
    func didHitCancel() {
        //do a function
    }

    func didHitOK() {
        //do another function
    }
    var stringy = "Hello"

    @IBAction func ButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {

        let otherVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AlertVC") as! AlertVC
        otherVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        otherVC.delegate = self
        otherVC.label.text = stringy //THIS is where my question focuses
        self.present(otherVC, animated: true, completion: nil)//presents the other VC modally

    }
```

The `otherVC` has a UILabel named "label". The issue I run into, though, when running the `ButtonAction` function is that xcode finds a fatal error because it unexpectedly found nil when unwrapping an optional value. I am a bit confused as to why this occurs, because putting in a print statement within `ButtonAction` confirms that `stringy` is not nil. The label in the `otherVC` is 'set up' correctly so I am not sure what is  giving the nil value.

Comment: Have you tried to pass the value as a string and set the label on viewDidLoad in your AlertVC? I think your label is still nil before you present the view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your label is available until you present your view controller.  Pass the string instead and set your label text in your  `AlertVC` `viewDidLoad` method.

in your `AlertVC` declare a string:

```
var stringy:String?
```

then change your code

```
 @IBAction func ButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {

        let otherVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AlertVC") as! AlertVC
        otherVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        otherVC.delegate = self
        otherVC.stringy = stringy //you pass the string instead of setting the label text
        self.present(otherVC, animated: true, completion: nil)//presents the other VC modally

    }
```

at this point you can set the text label in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
   self.label.text = self.stringy
```

Comment: how would I pass the string? I am familiar with using things like `override func prepare(for segue: )` but since there is no real segue, the VC is being presented modally, how do I pass the information?